# Некорректный совет среды разработки или я неверно понимаю правила языка?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, foreach

Есть класс Account обладающий списком `ArrayList<Card> cardList`.
В цикле мне требуется искать подходящий объект класса `Card`, и при соблюдении требуемых параметров обновлять строку и обновлять сам объект класса `Card` из списка `cardList`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cardList.size(); i++) {
 if (cardList.get(i).multi_parent != null && cardList.get(i).multi_parent.equals(multi_parentEntry)) {
     outputStr += cardList.get(i).balance;
     cardList.get(i).multi = true;
 }
```

}

Среда разработки Idea предупреждает, что  `'for' loop replaceable with 'foreach'`.

Поясните, пожалуйста, в чем тут проблема? Если я верно понимаю предупреждение, среда разработки предлагает использовать более компактный способ объявления цикла - foreach, но тут возникает вопрос - разве при объявлении цикла подобным образом

```
for (Card card: cardList) {
  if (card.multi_parent != null && card.multi_parent.equals(multi_parentEntry)) {
    outputStr += card.balance;
    card.multi = true;
  }
}
```

разве будет обновляться параметры объектов из списка (в моем случае каждый объект класса Card из списка cardList)?

Comment: а почему бы и нет? И она не предупреждает, а советует.

Comment: кроме того: в foreach запрещено изменение _самой коллекции_ а не конкретного элемента.

Comment: @Grundy а что Вы подразумеваете под изменением "самой коллекции"? Я правильно вас понимаю - имеется ввиду удаление/добавление элементов, например?

Comment: @mamba0767, да, именно это

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Возьмём следующий код:

```
ArrayList<Card> cardList;
for (Card card : cardList) {
    // . . .
    card.multi = true;
}
```

Фактически этот код эквивалентен следующему:

```
ArrayList<Card> cardList;
for (Iterator<Card> iter = cardList.iterator; iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Card card = iter.next();
    // . . . 
    card.multi = true;
}
```

На самом деле цикл `foreach` будет развёрнут в цикл с итераторами и `foreach` просто более короткая запись этого цикла. В коде с итераторами видно, что никаких копий элементов списка не создаётся, а в переменной `card` хранится ссылка на объект из списка. Поэтому изменение переменной `card` меняет элемент списка.

Тем самым, предложение *IntelliJ IDEA* абсолютно верно, предложенный ею код эквивалентен исходному.

Comment: @kiff Благодарю за развернутый ответ и пример с итератором, я, не знаю с чего, всегда считал будто с объекта, который мы используем, можно брать параметры, но изменяя его, мы не изменяем аналогичный объект, который взяли из списка, то есть мы работали с копией объекта из списка